# Group summary notification not canceled when last containing notification is canceled

Tags: android, notifications

I have created a notification for group summary, which may contain many notifications.
Those notifications have some actions added by `addAction()`.

I try to cancel the notification after a action has been made:

```
NotitifactionCompat.from(context).cancel(notificationId);
```

Unfortunately, when the canceled notification was the last one of the summary, only the notification itself will be canceled, but not the summary too.

What am i missing?

Comment: I know that was quite a long time ago, but did you find a solution?

Answer (score 13):

Had the same problem. I cancel notification programmatically when I tap notification action. If you swipe it out it works well. I do this workaround:

```
public static void cancelNotification(Context context, int notifyId, int summeryId) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    boolean cancelSummary = false;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N && summeryId != 0) {
        StatusBarNotification[] statusBarNotifications = notificationManager.getActiveNotifications();
        String groupKey = null;

        for (StatusBarNotification statusBarNotification : statusBarNotifications) {
            if (notifyId == statusBarNotification.getId()) {
                groupKey = statusBarNotification.getGroupKey();
                break;
            }
        }

        int counter = 0;
        for (StatusBarNotification statusBarNotification : statusBarNotifications) {
            if (statusBarNotification.getGroupKey().equals(groupKey)) {
                counter++;
            }
        }

        if (counter == 2) {
            cancelSummary = true;
        }
    }

    if (cancelSummary) {
        notificationManager.cancel(summeryId);
    } else {
        notificationManager.cancel(notifyId);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, great answer
these kind of answers you can't find in chatgpt and others.

Answer (score 12):

`setAutoCancel(true)` to the summary Notification solved my problem of summary notification being left in the tray.

Comment: If you cancel notification programmatically summary notification won't be cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

The summary notification is not automatically cancelled when all the grouped notifications are programmatically cancelled. From *[Correctly handling bundled Android notifications](http://blog.danlew.net/2017/02/07/correctly-handling-bundled-android-notifications/)*:

> Obviously, you're going to need to keep track of new notifications. But this also means you have to keep track of notifications that have been dismissed. Otherwise, the summary might still contain information about notifications no longer contained within the bundle.